# back-sides effects and overloading

Tags: c++, function, overloading

is there any 'smart' overload of functions in c++?

for simple:

```
  classname classname::Foo(const classname& t){
     classname workVar = t.clone(); 
                   //great work, like this GREAT(), that changing workVar;
     return workVar;
  }

                    //back-side effect here, changing object
  void classname::Foo(){
     classname workVar = (*this).clone();
                    //the same, GREAT() changing workVar
     (*this).copy(workVar);
  }
```

is there any possible ways to merge this two functions in one?

in first way, for changing current object:

```
   obj = obj.Foo(obj);
```

in second way:

```
   obj.Foo();
```

how to merging these functions into one withouht redefining functions?

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second Foo() you specify a "this" but it doesn't look like a class member function. Is it classname::Foo()?

clone() normally returns a pointer to a newly created object that is the same as the one you created. You would therefore assign it to a pointer variable. Whilst it could return a reference, it would be confusing as you would need to manage it, i.e. delete it later, and you wouldn't normally expect to do that to a reference.

You would not assign the clone to a new object as you are doing.

`this.` is not valid syntax in C++, as "this" is always a pointer.

If your general question is whether an external function called Foo that takes a const T& can automatically call `T::Foo`, well `boost::bind` actually does something quite clever with that in that you can do something like

```
boost::bind( &classname::Foo, workVar )
```

from outside and

```
boost::bind( &classname::Foo, this )
```

from within and if it's a free function then

```
boost::bind( Foo, workVar )
```

also works, each of them creating a function that takes no parameters, although in your case they have different returns types, so it won't work for your particular example.

`